# Apache POI createTable generates corrupted file when a header's cell contains a line break

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using **Apache POI 4.1.2** to create Excel files in Java. I have a piece of code that creates a table from existing cells and everything used to work fine, untill I had a linebreak inside a header's cell.

I tried to change the table's column name afterward but it didn't fix anything.

Below is a minimal piece of code to reproduce the problem:

```
    public void test() throws IOException {
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

        // headers
        XSSFRow headersRow = sheet.createRow(0);
        headersRow.createCell(0).setCellValue("Column1");
        headersRow.createCell(1).setCellValue("Column2");

        // a second row
        XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(1);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(1);
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(2);

        // create a table
        AreaReference area = wb.getCreationHelper().createAreaReference(
                new CellReference(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0)),
                new CellReference(sheet.getRow(1).getCell(1))
        );
        XSSFTable table = sheet.createTable(area);

        // styling (no problem here)
        sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 5000);
        sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 5000);
        CTTable cttable = table.getCTTable();
        cttable.addNewTableStyleInfo();
        XSSFTableStyleInfo style = (XSSFTableStyleInfo) table.getStyle();
        style.setName("TableStyleMedium6");
        style.setShowColumnStripes(false);
        style.setShowRowStripes(true);
        cttable.addNewAutoFilter().setRef(area.formatAsString());
        CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
        cellStyle.setWrapText(true);
        headersRow.getCell(0).setCellStyle(cellStyle);

        // this file is OK
        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\tmp\\test.xlsx")) {
            wb.write(outputStream);
        }

        // add a line break in a header's cell
        headersRow.getCell(0).setCellValue("Column1\nwith a line break");
        // this file has a problem
        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\tmp\\test2.xlsx")) {
            wb.write(outputStream);
        }

        // this doesn't fix anything
        table.getColumns().get(0).setName("Column1");
        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\tmp\\test3.xlsx")) {
            wb.write(outputStream);
        }

        // neither does this
        cttable.getTableColumns().getTableColumnList().get(0).setName("Column1");
        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\tmp\\test4.xlsx")) {
            wb.write(outputStream);
        }
    }
```

Excel loads **text.xlsx** properly, but complains about all other files:
*We found a problem with some content...*

After Excel fixes the files, everything is OK but I would like to get rid of the warning message.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an inaccuracy with [XSSFTable.updateHeaders](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFTable.html#updateHeaders--). This method gets called while the table's `XML` gets written. This is because the table column names always must be synchronized with the cell contents. For example if the cell content is "Column1" and this cell is a column header of a table, then this tables column name also must be "Column1" (XML: `<tableColumn id="1" name="Column1"/>`).

But for line feeds in column headers, there is a specialty. If the cell content is "Column1\nwith a line break" and this cell is a column header of a table, then this tables column name must be XML as `<tableColumn id="1" name="Column1_x000a_with a line break"/>`. So "\n"  is replaced by "*x000a*". Also "\r" would must be replaced by "*x000d*". This is because "\r\n" line breaks will not have the meaning of line break in `XML`.

So [XSSFTable.java - updateHeaders](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_1_2/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFTable.java?view=markup#l811) would must be patched that way that "\n" gets replaced by "*x000a*" and "\r" gets replaced by "*x000d*".

```
...
    public void updateHeaders() {
        XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet)getParent();
        CellReference ref = getStartCellReference();
        if (ref == null) return;

        int headerRow = ref.getRow();
        int firstHeaderColumn = ref.getCol();
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(headerRow);
        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

        if (row != null && row.getCTRow().validate()) {
            int cellnum = firstHeaderColumn;
            CTTableColumns ctTableColumns = getCTTable().getTableColumns();
            if(ctTableColumns != null) {
                for (CTTableColumn col : ctTableColumns.getTableColumnList()) {
                    XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(cellnum);
                    if (cell != null) {
                        String colName = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                        colName = colName.replace("\n", "_x000a_");
                        colName = colName.replace("\r", "_x000d_");
                        col.setName(colName);
                    }
                    cellnum++;
                }
            }
        }
        tableColumns = null;
        columnMap = null;
        xmlColumnPrs = null;
        commonXPath = null;
    }
...
```

Since  [XSSFTable.updateHeaders](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFTable.html#updateHeaders--) gets called while the table's `XML` gets written while `XSSFWorkbook.write`, there is no other way than patching this method. One does not have any chance to change table's `XML` while `XSSFWorkbook.write`.

Comment: Thank you Axel. It seems there is no workaround for the time being then. I filled in a new bug here : https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64732